# Moving Local Changes Into a Branch

Tags: svn, branch

I've been working in the trunk today and now I am needing to take some changes I've made out of the trunk and move them into a branch.  I haven't committed any of these changes yet.  But I need to create a branch then get these files into that branch.  I have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add a new branch to the repository:

```
 svn copy $base/trunk $base/branches/my-branch
```

and then switch your WC to it:

```
 svn switch $base/branches/my-branch
```

Comment: `svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/my-branch` this is what worked for me